# Assert type of global using TypeScript assertion function?

Tags: typescript, assertion, webcrypto-api, typeguards

Is it possible to create a TypeScript assertion function that asserts the type of something other than the arguments passed to it – a global, for instance:

```
// Pseudo-code
function assertIsSubtleCryptoSupported(
): asserts globalThis.crypto.subtle is InstanceType<SubtleCrypto> {
  if (globalThis.crypto?.subtle === undefined) {
    throw new Error('...');
  }
}

globalThis.crypto.subtle; // Type error
assertIsSubtleCryptoSupported();
globalThis.crypto.subtle; // OK
```

Comment: Does this work? `function assert(global: unknown): asserts global is {crypto: {subtle: type}} {}` and using `assert(global)`

Comment: My understanding is along the lines of @wonderflame's. It's definitely [possible](https://tsplay.dev/w1kQOm) (through property access) to assert something about a global, though.

Comment: The answer to the question is: no, an assertion function can only affect the apparent type of one of its arguments... *or* it can affect the apparent type of the object on which it's called (that is, an assertion *method* returning `asserts this is ⋯`).  There's no facility to affect other values in other scopes.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I think that you're technically correct @jcalz (the best kind of correct).

Comment: @wonderflame's answer is a good alternative. You should both write up your answers! https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&module=6#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoAoD6AbsgDYgYBci4A1mHAO5gCUVamOqiRp5iMXAN4QsATwAOUOFUGoQAIyglKiAMoKlGAMJjJcAL77Eg-QChTEBKiiIA5ogC8dknHmkAKgAsBKLrXpMANym7Nh4tszBprYAdCISUjFyisoxthhg2MhQGADSGKKBiAD0xYgA8rlAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) and [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) can only affect their arguments.

Alternatively, you could write an assertion function and pass `global` to it to infer its properties:

```
function assert(arg: unknown): asserts arg is {crypto: {subtle2: 'str'}} {}
```

Testing:

```
assert(global);

global.crypto.subtle2 // 'str'
```